# get content from facebook url using php

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl

How to get content from facebook url and extract facebook user id and access token. I have used CURL and it's returning empty content.

```
            $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$fbconfig['appid'].'&redirect_uri='.$returnurl.'&client_secret='.$fbconfig['secret'].'&code='.$_REQUEST['code'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
        ));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

      $iResult=AlowUserAccess();

 $FBUserId = explode('|', $iResult);
$FBUserId = explode('|', $FBUserId['1']);
$FBUserId = explode('-', $FBUserId['0']);

$iUserId = $FBUserId['1'];

$iUserId = $iResult;
$sAccessToken = explode('access_token=', $iResult);
```

Comment: Why haven't you used the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)? It'll be **MUCH** easier...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the options used here:

[PHP script to automate login and form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588073/php-script-to-automate-login-and-form-submit/16600780#16600780)

Your not setting both SSL opts, it is also possible they may want to set a cookie.