# Auto login into gmail account using php

Tags: php, email, csv, curl, authentication

I have the gmail login credintals. Is it possible to login automatically to Gmail if we pass the username and password through url or by CURL.

I need to be login into gmail account before run my some php code.

Is there any php function or script that run first by passing gmail username and password and make login into browser.

can you provide a complete php code for login into gmail account just by passing username and password.

I am working on google trends. I need to be get csv file of google trends.
I have function that generate the google trend url for particular key word.
when I manually login into gmail account below link  allow me to download csv file.

[http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-US&q=search,&geo=US&date=today 7-d&gprop=&cmpt=q&content=1&export=1](http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-US&q=search,&geo=US&date=today%207-d&gprop=&cmpt=q&content=1&export=1)

If your login into gmail account and click on above link, will allow you to download report.csv file.

I need this csv file to be download into my project directory, say into upload folder.

So, basically I need, one script that login me into gmail account and one script that allow to download report.csv file into upload directory.

If any one has solution for above problem, please provide a solution here.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/

Comment: doesn't google auth with OAuth? There are plenty of OAauth PHP libs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about schemas as linked by Dainis; however, briefly looking through the website I don't know that I would be confident that would work.

I' feel you might be looking in the wrong direction. If all you are trying to do is automate something from the browser side, use JavaScript. You can create a bookmarklet that will fill out a Google login form and then automatically go to a URL to download a CSV. I'd imagine most if not all of what you are trying to do can be done using JavaScript and if not, you can use JavaScript to automate authentication and then load a PHP page with the rest of the code.

If you insist on using PHP Try checking this question out and good luck:

[PHP script to automate login and form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588073/php-script-to-automate-login-and-form-submit)